# How Trick to change many form,textbox,button properties with programmatically in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Please Help, I have create 5 form, 3 textboxt and 1 button in 1 form. I know to change the control properties. In example i want to change the FormBorderStyle to FixedSingle. Here is below code

```
Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle
```

it's not problem if I work with less form, Any trick for this problem? Like just simple code to change all form,textbox, and button properties? It's is possible?

Thanks, any respond are appreciate! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one Class for formstyle like

```
    Imports System
    Imports System.Windows.Forms
    Public Class FormStyle
        Public Sub FormCreation(frmName As Form)
            frmName.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Apply to all forms like

```
    Public Class Form1
        Dim frm As New FormStyle
        Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            frm.FormCreation(Me)
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: Thanks Senthilkumar :) last question, how about textbox? just change paramenter in sub? like "public sub textboxstyle(txtname as textbox)"? and no need to change "import system.windows.form"? Thanks kumar..